# How to use custom template for event details in angular bootstrap calendar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am using Calendar Control (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) for my project. I have used custom template URL for calendar month view and I want to change the format they provide for event details. For example, have a look at this image
[image]

Here I want to change the template and make the time of the event disappear. I couldn't find any example so I posted here. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this resolved it for me. I chained this code to my angular.module, so instead of ending with a semi-colon, add the code.

```
       .run(function(calendarEventTitle) {
            calendarEventTitle.monthView = event => event.title;
        });
```