# AngularJS Bootstrap Calendar MWL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm trying to customize Matt Lewis's calendar, I've read the documentation and researched this but I can't find an easy solution. What I need to do is pretty straightforward, but I have no idea how to do it.

The Week view contains my event names, and I can click on that to launch my modal but that's where I am stuck.

I want that same functionality to appear in the Month view instead of the badge incremented label, and the slid down div.

I won't post lots of code here because I don't know what logic is the part that needs changing!

Here is a URL to the test site: [UI Calendar Test Site](http://purpletoothtigers.com/calendar/)

Comment: Worth a read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: The principle is sound but in this case it makes no sense, it's not something that is broken or throwing error messages at me. It is a well known calendar with many features, of which I want to alter. Anyone who knows this calendar well will know what I need to tweak and where. The only code I can paste is code that works and there is absolutely no point in that and if I knew which part of the original coed to post I would, but the point is I don't and am looking for direction.

Comment: Is the link to your own test site, or to the calendar author's test site? Either way, but for the former especially, once you fix the problem (or delete the test site) the question will become broken. That is why we need questions to illustrate the problem in the question itself. Can you show the feature/problem in the Stack Overflow built-in editor? That will preserve the question for posterity.

Comment: This is to my test site. I understand what you are saying but I have seen many questions like mine without code as it's an odd case. In fact I answered a question about the calendar for someone else just a few days ago, he did not present any code. For something like this I have no problem documenting the solution for others by way of screenshots and code, I just don't know what code to alter or where it is yet! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689980/how-to-use-custom-template-for-event-details-in-angular-bootstrap-calendar?rq=1)